# How to read strings from scala spark-shell Array[String]

Tags: scala

I have a XML file that I'm trying to process through Spark-Shell using Scala. I am stuck at a point where I need to read the Array[String] using Scala's

```
scala> val fileRead = sc.textFile("source_file")
fileRead: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = source_file MapPartitionsRDD[8] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> val strLines = fileRead.map(x => x.toString)
strLines: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at <console>:23

scala> val fltrLines = strLines.filter(_.contains("<record column1="))
fltrLines: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[10] at filter at <console>:25

scala> fltrLines.take(5)
res1: Array[String] = Array("<record column1="1" column2="1" column3="5" column4="2010-11-02T18:59:01.140" />", "<record column2=....
```

I need to read this value of the Array[String]:

```
"<record column1="1" column2="1" column3="5" column4="2010-11-02T18:59:01.140" />"
```

as XML so that I can use Scala Elem and NodeSeq classes to extract the data. So I want to do something like:

```
val xmlLines = fltrLines.....somehow get the value of the value of Array[String] first index
```

And then use xmlLines.attributes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `fltrLines.map { scala.xml.XML.loadString _ }`, which should build `Elem`s out of Strings. Check the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.xml.Elem), notice though that this is an old Scaladoc, when Scala std. lib. still contained XML, these days it resides in a separate jar file. So, if you are using a newer version, make sure to put the right jar in your classpath.

Comment: Perfect, I ended up doing this `scala> val element = fltrLines.map{ scala.xml.XML.loadString _ }`. Now I am trying to concatenate the attributes with a comma separator. `scala> val elementAttributes = element.map(_.attributes(column1)) and concatenate a comma and then column2, etc` Trying to sift through the documentation you provided. Thank you!

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but apparently I don't have 15 reputations to upvote your answer.